# Is it possible to run SQL query of SQLite Storage in react-native-background-job React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a Pill Reminder app which needs to be set reminders for pills.
what I need to do is-

- perform a background process and fetch reminders from SQLite Storage.
- if there is a reminder than shoot a local notification

The libraries I'm using-

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-job

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage

I have implemented the background process which is running fine

```
import BackgroundJob from 'react-native-background-job';
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

//this is the function is getting invoked in background 
const pushNoti = () => {

    var db = SQLite.openDatabase({ name: "MedCare.db", createFromLocation: 1 }, this.okCallback, this.errorCallback);

    db.transaction((tx) => {

        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM reminders', [], (tx, results) => {

            var len = results.rows.length;

            if(len > 0){

                PushNotification.localNotification({

                    title: "Its time to take you Pills",

                });

            }

        });

    });

}

const backgroundJob = {
    jobKey: "myPillReminders",
    job: () => pushNoti()
};

BackgroundJob.register(backgroundJob);

export defalt class Reminder extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

        var backgroundSchedule = {
            jobKey: "myPillReminders",
            period: 5000,
            exact: true,
            allowExecutionInForeground: true
        }

        BackgroundJob.schedule(backgroundSchedule);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please give us a snippet of what you already tried to do ?

Comment: updated, please check

Comment: Thank you ! To go further, can you please provide a specific question ? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask